# PowerShell calculates wrong

Tags: powershell, math

By accident I came across this simple math equation which PowerShell gets wrong.

```
PS 99.804-99.258
0.546000000000006

PS 10.804-10.258
0.546000000000001
```

This made me curious and I tried some different calculators and most Calculator gets it right and return

```
0.546
```

And:

```
PS 1.804-1.258
0.546
```

is correct too.
But I found other calculators that also returned wrong results:

```
0.54600000000001
0.545999999999999999
0.5460000000000065
```

Why does this happen and how can I get the correct result in PowerShell?

Comment: So how to get around it in PowerShell?

Comment: This is why I posted my answer, you can try it.

Comment: Yeah, while the question linked as a duplicate is present, it's a generic answer that doesn't describe how to resolve the problem with PowerShell (use the `[decimal]` data type).  The linked question should not be marked as a dupe here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the default type used in your example is [`System.Double`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx),

```
99.804.GetType()

>>>>IsPublic IsSerial Name                                    BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                    --------
    True     True     Double                                  System.ValueType
```

In your particular case, what you want to use is [`System.Decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) which is more *precise*,

```
[decimal]99.804-[decimal]99.258

>>>>0.546
```

or alternatively,

```
99.804d-99.258d

>>>>0.546
```

---

**Further information**

I felt the need to clarify what I meant by *more precise*. Basically, it is important to understand that `double` type has a much more larger range than `decimal` type. But, **larger range doesn't mean more accurate.**

Actually, `System.Decimal` was initially created to take care of currency/money problem where decimal point can be a mess. **It's preciseness rely in the fact that it uses base-10 math instead of base-2 math for `System.Double`**. Obviously, the latter is much more efficient to calculate but less accurate.

This can be validated here in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types#nonintegral-numeric-types) where it states that,

> You can use `Decimal` variables for money values. The advantage is the precision of the values. The `Double` data type is faster and requires less memory, but it is subject to rounding errors. The `Decimal` data type retains complete accuracy to 28 decimal places.
>
> Floating-point (`Single` and `Double`) numbers have larger ranges than `Decimal` numbers but can be subject to rounding errors. Floating-point types support fewer significant digits than `Decimal` but can represent values of greater magnitude.

Comment: For more detail as to _why_ this happens you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?noredirect=1&lq=1